# Wifi connection is weak (rtl8723be)

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking, drivers

My laptop's WiFi card is rtl8723be. It keeps disconnecting even when the hotspot is two metres away. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install these drivers: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/

All the instructions are in the README of the project. Simply replace `<<YOUR WIRELESS DRIVER CODE>>` by `rtl8723be`. If it still doesn't work, try to edit the driver's options as explained in the README, and write:

`options rtl8723be ant_sel=0`

And reload it with the two `modprobe` commands. You'll probably need to change this value between 0, 1 and 2 to find the best working antenna for your card.

Note that these drivers need to be recompiled every time you install a newer version of the kernel.